# systemd unit that's needed by multiple targets and stops when target stops

Tags: service, systemd

I have a set of units that need to be run with multiple targets that come after multi-user.target.

Example:

multi-user.target <--> example1.target <--> example2.target <--> multi-use.target

Example target:

```
[Unit]
Description=Example target
Wants=multi-user.target
Requires=example.service
#PropagatesStopTo=example.service
Conflicts=rescue.service rescue.target
After=multi-user.target basic.target rescue.service rescue.target
```

Example service unit:

```
[Unit]
Description=Example unit
After=multi-user.target
Wants=multi-user.target

[Service]
Environment=Some Enviroment
ExecStart=Some Binary
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=1
Type=simple

[Install]
WantedBy=example1.target example2.target
```

The main problem is when I try too stop the currently running target none of the Required units stop.
I've tried using PropagatesStopTo=example.service in the target with no success. Below is output:
/lib/systemd/system/example1.target:7: Unknown key name 'PropagatesStopTo' in section 'Unit', ignoring.
My systemd version is:
systemd 241 (241-166-g511646b+)
I know my systemd doesn't support PropagatesStopTo so I'm trying to find an alternative in my current systemd version.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the below in the service file.

```
PartOf=example1.target
```

This adds a `ConsistsOf` dependency on the unit in the target.

From Systemd page

> Configures dependencies similar to Requires=, but limited to stopping and restarting of units. When systemd stops or restarts the units listed here, the action is propagated to this unit. Note that this is a one-way dependency — changes to this unit do not affect the listed units.
>
> When PartOf=b.service is used on a.service, this dependency will show
> as ConsistsOf=a.service in property listing of b.service. ConsistsOf=
> dependency cannot be specified directly.

Read more [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html)